# Unable to HTTP post data using Retrofit but able to post using commandline

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Unable to HTTP post data using Retrofit but able to post using commandline. I have added required headers in Interceptor but still it's failing.

For Android app it returns code 500/Internal error. For commandline using curl , it returns code as 200, so there is no issue at server side.

Android Code:  It returns response code as 500/Internal error

```
  private void postData(String data) {
        Toast.makeText(settingFragmentView.getContext(),"Inside postData function",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        // on below line we are creating a retrofit
        // builder and passing our base url

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor( HeaderInterceptor())
                .build();


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://locserver2.lab.acs.altran.fr")
                .client(okHttpClient)
                // as we are sending data in json format so
                // we have to add Gson converter factory
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                // at last we are building our retrofit builder.
                .build();

        // below line is to create an instance for our retrofit api class.
        RetrofitAPI retrofitAPI = retrofit.create(RetrofitAPI.class);

        // passing data from our text fields to our modal class.
        DataModal modal = new DataModal(data);

        // calling a method to create a post and passing our modal class.
        Call<DataModal> call = retrofitAPI.createPost(modal);



        // on below line we are executing our method.
        call.enqueue(new Callback<DataModal>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DataModal> call, Response<DataModal> response) {

                
                // we are getting response from our body
                // and passing it to our modal class.
                DataModal responseFromAPI = response.body();

                // on below line we are getting our data from modal class and adding it to our string.
                String responseString = "Response Code : " + response.code();
                Toast.makeText(settingFragmentView.getContext(), "Data posted to HTTP server with response code : " + responseString , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DataModal> call, Throwable t) {
                
                Toast.makeText(settingFragmentView.getContext(), "HTTP Post Failure...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }

    private Interceptor HeaderInterceptor() {
        return new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                okhttp3.Request request = chain.request();
                            request = request.newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                            .addHeader("Content-type","application/json")
                            .build();


                okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);
                Log.e("headers", request.toString());
               // Toast.makeText(settingFragmentView.getContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return response;
            }
        };
    }
```

Commandline: It returns response code as 200

```
curl -v -H 'Content-type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ "tagId": "0x0002", "tagData": { "batteryLevel": 89, "socialDistancingInfo":"0x0001;1.93;1618402644;yes" }, "contact": [ {"ID": "0x0001"}], "presence": { "value": "notpresent" } }' https://locserver2.lab.acs.altran.fr/locationEngine/default/tagValues -X POST --http1.1
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 81.255.173.66...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to locserver2.lab.acs.altran.fr (81.255.173.66) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=locserver.lab.acs.altran.fr
*  start date: Apr 30 14:58:25 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Jul 29 14:58:25 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "locserver2.lab.acs.altran.fr" matched cert's "locserver2.lab.acs.altran.fr"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /locationEngine/default/tagValues HTTP/1.1
> Host: locserver2.lab.acs.altran.fr
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Content-type: application/json
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Length: 180
> 
* upload completely sent off: 180 out of 180 bytes
**< HTTP/1.1 200 OK**
< Date: Fri, 28 May 2021 12:14:30 GMT
< Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< X-Powered-By: web2py
< Expires: Fri, 28 May 2021 12:14:30 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Set-Cookie: session_id_locationengine=10.1.90.1-6e6fee2f-8c56-4d6f-b685-0aa6a8283011; httponly; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host locserver2.lab.acs.altran.fr left intact
```

Comment: I am sending string \"tagId\": \"x01\", \"tagData\": {\"batteryLevel\": 89},\"contact\": {\"ID\": \"x02\"},\"presence\": \"value\": \"present\"}" +
                "}" in the postData function. But once I call the API to post this string it adds "data" while sending the json string.

Comment: D/OkHttp: --> POST https://locserver.lab.acs.altran.fr/locationEngine/default/tagValues
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 137
D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json
D/OkHttp: Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
D/OkHttp: {"data":"{\"tagId\": \"x01\", \"tagData\": {\"batteryLevel\": 89},\"contact\": {\"ID\": \"x02\"},\"presence\": \"value\": \"present\"}}"}
D/OkHttp: --> END POST (137-byte body)